# GNOME Network Displays on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mirrors

I've tested several things to get my projector working with Ubuntu, but only [GNOME Network Displays](https://github.com/benzea/gnome-network-displays) comes close. After establishing the connection, I get errors:

```
(gnome-network-displays:39996): WARNING **: 22:50:06.762: WfdClient: No resolution found, falling back to standard FullHD resolution.

(gnome-network-displays:39996): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:50:06.901: g_source_set_callback: assertion 'source != NULL' failed

(gnome-network-displays:39996): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:50:06.901: g_source_attach: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
```

What do you think may be the issue?

The projector documentation mention support for IOS and Android only.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it works. Probably my installation from source was not done properly.
Using flatpak make it very easy.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
```

To run the app:

```
flatpak run org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
```

Comment: It runs and the TV screen shows the cast icon, nothing more. Any more steps to cast the screen? Thanks.